# Timed selector never performed

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa, selector

I've added an observer for my method:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self 
                                         selector:@selector(closeViewAfterUpdating) 
                                             name:@"labelUpdatedShouldReturn" 
                                           object:nil];
```

Then my relevant methods:

```
-(void)closeViewAfterUpdating; {
NSLog(@"Part 1 called");
[self performSelector:@selector(closeViewAfterUpdating2) withObject:nil afterDelay:2.0];
}

-(void)closeViewAfterUpdating2; {
NSLog(@"Part 2 called");
[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

The only reason why I've split this method into two parts is so that I can have a delay before the method is fired.

The problem is, the second method is never called.  My `NSLog` output shows `Part 1 called`, but it never fires part 2.  Any ideas?

**EDIT: I'm calling the notification from a background thread, does that make a difference by any chance?**

Here's how I'm creating my background thread:

```
[NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(getWeather) toTarget:self withObject:nil];
```

and in `getWeather` I have:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"updateZipLabel" object:textfield.text];
```

Also, calling:

```
[self performSelector:@selector(closeViewAfterUpdating2) withObject:nil];
```

*does* work.

**EDITx2: I fixed it.  Just needed to post the notification in my main thread and it worked just fine.**

Comment: I cannot duplicate the behavior you describe. I created a program that just calls your `closeViewAfterUpdating` method in the main function and runs the runloop, and `closeViewAfterUpdating2` executed just as expected two seconds later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The background thread is the problem. It has a non running run loop, thus the selector is never called. Just let the NSRunLoop or CFRunLoopRef object of the thread run while the selector isn't fired.

Comment: Slow down a minute genius.  You lost me around the run loop part.  Can you please elaborate further?

Comment: This sounds right. But you will likely cause weird crashes, etc depending on what you are doing, since that notification will come in on the background thread if you notify from there. You should call performSelectorOnMainThread to communicate from the background to the main 'usual' thread, unless you are familiar with @sychronize and other concepts.

Comment: **EDIT:** So maybe I should do this in my background thread: `[self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(postNotification)withObject:nil waitUntilDone:false];`, with the notification posted in `postNotification`?

Comment: Probably a bit late, but just for the record: The thing with timers is, that they are scheduled at an run loop. This is usually the default run loop which by default also runs (this means, has an endless loop and processing input, firing timers etc). Every thread has its own run loop, and while the default run loop (read: main thread run loop) runs, all others aren't doing this by default. So if you want to use a timer or, in your case, a timed firing of an selector, you have the run loop force to run. If you don't do this, nothing happens as no events are dispatched.

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code and it works fine on my side. You might be doing something funky in the background that is interrupting your selector.

Answer (score 0):

You have a semi-colon in the method definition:

```
-(void)closeViewAfterUpdating2; {
```

Is this present in the code or a copy/paste issue?  That would be the problem on why you never see it called.

Comment: It's present in the code, and removing the semicolon does not fix the issue.  I always thought there was a semicolon after the method definition, is that not true?

Comment: It is needed in the declaration in the header file.  The definition in the .m file should not get a semi-colon.

Comment: I take that back, it is only a matter of style:  http://www.mail-archive.com/cocoa-dev@lists.apple.com/msg46310.html